# Says users is not used but it actually is ReactJS

Tags: reactjs

Why do I get an error saying that users and setUsers is not used when it is used in the select tag and in the getCompanyUsers const function? I used the exact same logic for the items and it didn't give me any error. I have tried separating the two functions in different useEffect functions but it gave the same error.

```
>Failed to compile.
>
>[eslint] 
>src\components\stock\DeleteItemForm.js
> Line 10:12:  'users' is assigned a value but never used     no-unused-vars
>  Line 10:19:  'setUsers' is assigned a value but never used  no-unused-vars
>
>Search for the keywords to learn more about each error.
```

```
function AssignItemForm(){
    const [items, setItems] = useState({});
    const [users, setUsers] = useState({});


    useEffect(() => {
      getCompanyItems(1);
      getCompanyUsers(1);
    }, []);

    const getCompanyItems = (company_id) => {
      const data = qs.stringify({ 'company': company_id });
      const csrftoken = getCookie('csrftoken');

      axios.post('/api/getcompanyitems', data, {
        headers: { 'X-CSRFToken': csrftoken }
      })
        .then(response => {
          setItems(response.data);
        })
        .catch(error => {
          console.log(error);
        });
    };

    const getCompanyUsers = (company_id) => {
      const data = qs.stringify({ 'company': company_id });
      const csrftoken = getCookie('csrftoken');
  
      axios.post('/api/getcompanyusers', data, {
        headers: { 'X-CSRFToken': csrftoken }
      })
        .then(response => {
          setUsers(response.data);
        })
        .catch(error => {
          console.log(error);
        });
    };

    return (
      <div>
        <div className='stock-form-container'>
          <h1>ASSIGN ITEM</h1>
          <form method='POST' action='/api/assignitem'>
            <input type="hidden" name="csrfmiddlewaretoken" value={csrftoken} />
            Item ID *
            <br/>
            <select placeholder='' name='item_id'>
              {
                Object.keys(items).map(itemId => (
                <option key={itemId} value={itemId}>{itemId}, {items[itemId].type_of_item}, Assigned to : {items[itemId].assigned_to}</option>
                ))
              }
            </select>
            <br/>
            Assigned to *
            <br/>
            <select placeholder='' name='assigned_to'>
              {
                Object.keys(users).map(userId => (
                <option key={userId} value={userId}>{userId}, {users[userId].name} {users[userId].lastname}</option>
                ))
              }
            </select>
            <br/>
            <input type='hidden' name='redirect' value='/stock' />
            <input type='submit'/>
          </form>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
}
```

Comment: Did you read the error? It's coming from file `DeleteItemForm.js` but you're showing us `AssignItemForm`

Answer (score -1):

you just need to attach the code related to:

> src\components\stock\DeleteItemForm.js

generally, this error is a linting error more that a code error and can be disabled or lower it's severity to warning rather than error.